# I am converting a Bootstrap theme into Wordpress but I cannot get my scripts to load in and run

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my repos on GitHub for the theme: https://github.com/RyanChrist4/ryanstrap

What I have done is removed the script tags from the head and put them into the functions.php file using the wp_register_script function and the wp_enqueue_script function. I have looked at the answers for other peoples similair questions and tried formatting it like them but I still cant get the scripts to run. I am new to web development and new to Wordpress. Also, in the header, there is a script tag that is calling multiple function but I get an error in the console that says "Uncaught Reference error.

Here is my the code in my functions.php file:

```
    <?php
//jQuery Insert From Google
if (!is_admin()) add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "my_jquery_enqueue");
function my_jquery_enqueue() {
   wp_deregister_script('jquery');
   wp_register_script('jquery', "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js", false, null);
   wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
//Launches all of the scripts below
add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "launch_scripts");
function launch_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('the-flexslider', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/jquery.flexslider-min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('the-fitvids', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/jquery.fitvids.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('the-smoothscroll', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/jquery.smooth-scroll.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('the-backstretch', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/jquery.backstretch.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('the-bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/bootstrap.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('the-bootstrapmin', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'the-gmaps', get_template_directory_uri() . '/http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js', array(), '20120206', true );
    wp_enqueue_script('the-mgmaps', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/gmaps.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('the-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/script.js');
}
?>
```

Here is the content of my header.php file:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" /> <!-- Its not valid html but it works -->
        <title><?php bloginfo( 'title' ); ?></title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <meta name="description" content="A very good admin theme" />
        <meta name="author" content="AHthemes" />
        <!--<script>menu(); backstretch(); slider(); contentslider(); map(); panels(); blogposts();</script>-->
        <!-- Le styles -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>"media="screen" />
        <!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="assets/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
        <!--[if gte IE 9]>
        <style type="text/css">
            .gradient { filter: none; }
        </style>
        <![endif]-->
        <!-- Fav and touch icons -->
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-144-precomposed.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-114-precomposed.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-72-precomposed.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-57-precomposed.png">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/ico/favicon.png">
<?php
  wp_head();
?>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="nav-section">
          <ul class="nav">
              <li><a href="#home" class="scroll home">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#about" class="scroll about">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="#work" class="scroll work">Work</a></li>
              <li><a href="#contact" class="scroll contact">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
      </div>
```

Comment: I think the problem could be with how I am calling my javascript funcitons in my header.php file

Comment: Could you elaborate on what "Uncaught reference error" you are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a JavaScript issue, compounded by WordPress.

Generally, when someone mentions "Uncaught reference error" it has to do with your scripts depending on something, and that thing not being loaded yet.

That's my hunch.
To do that, your code should be changed to the following -- I cleaned up your code :-)

Also fixed some code errors, you have one of your external scripts being loaded in badly (the gmap thing).

```
<?php

    // Replace Core jQuery version with 1.7.1 (Bootstrap Theme Requirement)
    // WordPress 4.5 includes 1.12.3
    // Only do this when we are not within the Administration area of WordPress.
    if (!is_admin()) {
        add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "replace_jquery");
    }

    function replace_jquery() {
        wp_deregister_script('jquery');
        wp_register_script('jquery', "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js", false, '1.7.1', false);
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    }

    // Load all of the scripts below, on every single page. :-\
    add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "launch_scripts");
    function launch_scripts() {
        $internal_path = get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/';
        wp_enqueue_script('the-flexslider', $internal_path . 'jquery.flexslider-min.js', array('jquery'));
        wp_enqueue_script('the-fitvids', $internal_path . 'jquery.fitvids.js', array('jquery'));
        wp_enqueue_script('the-smoothscroll', $internal_path . 'jquery.smooth-scroll.min.js', array('jquery'));
        wp_enqueue_script('the-backstretch', $internal_path . 'jquery.backstretch.min.js', array('jquery'));
        wp_enqueue_script('the-bootstrap', $internal_path . 'bootstrap.js', array('jquery'));
        wp_enqueue_script('the-bootstrapmin', $internal_path . 'bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'));
        wp_enqueue_script('the-gmaps', '//maps.google.com/maps/api/js', array('jquery'), '20120206', true);
        wp_enqueue_script('the-mgmaps', $internal_path . 'gmaps.js', array('jquery'));
        wp_enqueue_script('the-script', $internal_path . 'script.js', array('jquery'));
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I can believe the documentation, you don't need to register the script first:

> wp_enqueue_script - Registers the script if $src provided (does NOT overwrite), and enqueues it.

Read more [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/).

```
<?php
//jQuery Insert From Google
if (!is_admin()) add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "my_jquery_enqueue");
function my_jquery_enqueue() {
   wp_deregister_script('jquery');
   wp_register_script('jquery', "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js", false, null);
   wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
//Launches all of the scripts below
add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "launch_scripts");
function launch_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('the-flexslider', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/jquery.flexslider-min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('the-fitvids', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/jquery.fitvids.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('the-smoothscroll', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/jquery.smooth-scroll.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('the-backstretch', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/jquery.backstretch.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('the-bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/bootstrap.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('the-bootstrapmin', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'the-gmaps', '//maps.google.com/maps/api/js');
    wp_enqueue_script('the-mgmaps', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/gmaps.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('the-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/script.js');
}
?>
```

Comment: I tried using that but unfortunately it doesnt seem to fix the error

Comment: Still no luck. I think it could be that I am calling the functions wrong in the header.php.

Comment: I think that is a step in the right direction. But the Javascript is still not running. If you have a wordpress environment setup up you could download my theme and maybe get a better idea of what is going wrong https://github.com/RyanChrist4/ryanstrap

Comment: @RyanC, downloaded your theme, and this works for me. See updated answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

please try this line

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'the-gmaps', get_template_directory_uri() . '/http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js', array(), '20120206', true );
```

Comment: Ok, so that got rid of the warnings for the gmaps in the console but the javascript for everything else in my theme is not running

Comment: Please explain what your code does rather than just pasting a snippet on its own.